# How to use "style n args" with three or four arguments

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfkeys

In the next code I would like to use three or four arguments. 
I tried

`[add/.style args={#1 and #2 with #3}{to path={%
 ($(\tikztostart)!-#1!(\tikztotarget)$)--($(\tikztotarget)!-#2!(\tikztostart)$)%
  \tikztonodes coordinate[pos=-.25](#3)}}]`

but I'd like the `with #3` part to be optional.

```
\documentclass{standalone} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document} 

\begin{tikzpicture}[add/.style args={#1 and #2}{to path={%
 ($(\tikztostart)!-#1!(\tikztotarget)$)--($(\tikztotarget)!-#2!(\tikztostart)$)%
  \tikztonodes coordinate[pos=-.25](x)}}]

\coordinate (A) at (0,0);
\coordinate (B) at (3,2);
\draw[add=.5 and .5](A) to (B);
\foreach \point in {A,B,x}
\fill [red,opacity=.5] (\point) circle (2pt);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may want to try out a slightly different method. Just use one argument, which however is a list of keys. That way the syntax will always be the same even if you later decide to add some options/keys. These keys can have default/initial values, which can be changed at will. You can store these keys in a directory (I chose `Alain` here but you will of course change that), so you never run out of name space.

```latex
\documentclass{standalone} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
  add/.style={
    Alains settings={#1},
    to path={%
      ($(\tikztostart)!-\pv{first}!(\tikztotarget)$)--($(\tikztotarget)!-\pv{second}!(\tikztostart)$)%
      \tikztonodes coordinate[pos=\pv{pos}](\pv{coord})%
    }
  },
  Alains settings/.code={
    \tikzset{Alain/.cd,#1}
    \def\pv##1{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/Alain/##1}}
  },
  Alain/.cd,
    first/.initial=0.5,
    second/.initial=0.5,
    coord/.initial=x,
    pos/.initial=-0.25
]
  \coordinate (A) at (0,0);
  \coordinate (B) at (3,2);
  \draw[add](A) to (B);
  \foreach \point in {A,B,x}
  {\fill [red,opacity=.5] (\point) circle[radius=2pt] node[above]{\point};}

 \begin{scope}[xshift=5cm]
  \coordinate (A) at (0,0);
  \coordinate (B) at (3,2);
  \draw[add={first=0.3,second=0.8,coord=y,pos=-0.4}](A) to (B);
  \foreach \point in {A,B,y}
  {\fill [red,opacity=.5] (\point) circle[radius=2pt] node[above]{\point};}
 \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

In the left part the keys take their initial/default values but in the right part they get changed.

I personally find the usage also easier to remember.

Comment: Thanks ! another example to study! I've never used `\pgfkeysvalueof` this will be an opportunity to understand how it works. I saw from your answers that you like this method.

Comment: @AlainMatthes You're welcome! In a way this just copies what Ti*k*Z does all along. For instance, in decorations you can say `\draw[decorate,decoration={brace,mirror,raise=5pt},blue] ...`, i.e. pass multiple optional keys to the decoration, and if you don't, it will use the initial/default values. And yes, I do like this kind of usage a lot, I am even using it now for non-Ti*k*Z-related problems because you can always upgrade your macros while maintaining backwards compatibility, and IMHO the usage is easier to remember.