# How to draw a figure of number axis with some intervals indicated?

Tags: plot, draw

I want to draw a figure (in overleaf) as shown below: a number axis with some intervals indicated by circled number:
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Update 2 on request of OP

I created a new style called `from infty` to represent the interval from `-infinity`. To place text under the figures, I named the bounding box axe and placed a node underneath it.

```
from infty/.style args={#1of#2}{%<-- new style "from infty"
            to path={($(\tikztostart)!#1!90:(\tikztotarget)$).. controls ($(\tikztostart)!1-#2!(\tikztotarget)!#1!90:(\tikztotarget)$) 
                .. (\tikztotarget) \tikztonodes}}
```

[image: screenshot]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
%\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,calc,quotes}
\begin{document}

\tikzset{my curve/.style args={#1of#2}{
        to path={.. controls ($(\tikztostart)!#2!(\tikztotarget)!#1!90:(\tikztotarget)$) 
            and ($(\tikztostart)!1-#2!(\tikztotarget)!#1!90:(\tikztotarget)$) 
            .. (\tikztotarget)\tikztonodes}},
             my curve/.default={7mm of 0.25},
             to infty/.style args={#1of#2}{%<-- new style "to infty"
        to path={.. controls ($(\tikztostart)!#2!(\tikztotarget)!#1!90:(\tikztotarget)$) 
            .. ($(\tikztotarget)!#1!90:(\tikztotarget)$) \tikztonodes}},
            from infty/.style args={#1of#2}{%<-- new style "from infty"
        to path={($(\tikztostart)!#1!90:(\tikztotarget)$).. controls ($(\tikztostart)!1-#2!(\tikztotarget)!#1!90:(\tikztotarget)$) 
            .. (\tikztotarget) \tikztonodes}},
             to infty/.default={7mm of 0.4},
             from infty/.default={7mm of 0.4}}  

\begin{tikzpicture} [pics/tick/.style={code={\draw ++(0,-.2)node[below]{#1}--++(0,.4);}}]
\begin{scope}[local bounding box=axe]%<-- bounding box "axe"
\coordinate (z') at (-2,0);
\coordinate (c) at (1,0);
\coordinate (b) at (4,0);
\coordinate (a) at (6,0);
\coordinate (z) at (9,0);
\draw[-{Stealth[]}] (-2,0)--(10,0);
\pic at (c){tick=c};
\pic at (b){tick=b};
\pic at (a) {tick=a};
%\pic at (z) {tick};
\draw (z')to["4"{draw,circle},from infty](c) to["2"{draw,circle},my curve] (b) to ["3"{draw,circle},my curve] (a) to ["1"{draw,circle},to infty](z);
\end{scope}
\node[below] at (axe.south){My axis};%<-- node to add caption
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

## Update on request of the OP

I created a new style called `to infty` to represent the interval to infinity.
To place text under the figures, I named the bounding box `axe` and placed a node underneath it.

The code is commented out with `%<--` .

[image: screenshot]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
%\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,calc,quotes}
\begin{document}

\tikzset{my curve/.style args={#1of#2}{
        to path={.. controls ($(\tikztostart)!#2!(\tikztotarget)!#1!90:(\tikztotarget)$) 
            and ($(\tikztostart)!1-#2!(\tikztotarget)!#1!90:(\tikztotarget)$) 
            .. (\tikztotarget)\tikztonodes}},
             my curve/.default={7mm of 0.25},
             to infty/.style args={#1of#2}{%<-- new style "to infty"
        to path={.. controls ($(\tikztostart)!#2!(\tikztotarget)!#1!90:(\tikztotarget)$) 
            .. ($(\tikztotarget)!#1!90:(\tikztotarget)$) \tikztonodes}},
             to infty/.default={7mm of 0.4}}  

\begin{tikzpicture} [pics/tick/.style={code={\draw ++(0,-.2)node[below]{#1}--++(0,.4);}}]
\begin{scope}[local bounding box=axe]%<-- bounding box "axe"
\coordinate (c) at (1,0);
\coordinate (b) at (4,0);
\coordinate (a) at (6,0);
\coordinate (z) at (9,0);
\draw[-{Stealth[]}] (0,0)--(10,0);
\pic at (c){tick=c};
\pic at (b){tick=b};
\pic at (a) {tick=a};
%\pic at (z) {tick};
\draw (c) to["2"{draw,circle},my curve] (b) to ["3"{draw,circle},my curve] (a) to ["1"{draw,circle},to infty](z);
\end{scope}
\node[below] at (axe.south){My axis};%<-- node to add caption
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

#### Curve parameters

These two styles are set, by default, it appears the previous figure. It is possible to modify the **height** of the curve and its **curvature** with the following parameters.
For example `my curve=12mm of .4` means that the curve has a **height** of `12 mm` and that the **control points** of the bezier curve are located at `0.4` and `1-0.4=0.6` of the path.

[image: screenshot]

```
\draw (c) to["2"{draw,circle},my curve=12mm of .4] (b) to ["3"{draw,circle},my curve=8mm of .2] (a) to ["1"{draw,circle},to infty=15mm of .6](z);
```

## First answer

I reused the [my curve 7](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/556902/138900) code I wrote here.  I renamed it `my curve`.

```
\tikzset{my curve/.style args={#1of#2}{
        to path={.. controls ($(\tikztostart)!#2!(\tikztotarget)!#1!90:(\tikztotarget)$) 
            and ($(\tikztostart)!1-#2!(\tikztotarget)!#1!90:(\tikztotarget)$) 
            .. (\tikztotarget)\tikztonodes}},
             my curve/.default={7mm of 0.25}}
```

I defined a `pic` that allows you to draw a tick and write text underneath.

```
pics/tick/.style={code={\draw ++(0,-.2)node[below]{#1}--++(0,.4);}}
```

#### Result:

[image: screenshot]

#### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,calc,quotes}
\begin{document}

\tikzset{my curve/.style args={#1of#2}{
        to path={.. controls ($(\tikztostart)!#2!(\tikztotarget)!#1!90:(\tikztotarget)$) 
            and ($(\tikztostart)!1-#2!(\tikztotarget)!#1!90:(\tikztotarget)$) 
            .. (\tikztotarget)\tikztonodes}},
             my curve/.default={7mm of 0.25}}  

\begin{tikzpicture} [pics/tick/.style={code={\draw ++(0,-.2)node[below]{#1}--++(0,.4);}}]

\coordinate (c) at (1,0);
\coordinate (b) at (4,0);
\coordinate (a) at (6,0);
\coordinate (z) at (9,0);
\draw[-{Stealth[]}] (0,0)--(10,0);
\pic at (c){tick=c};
\pic at (b){tick=b};
\pic at (a) {tick=a};
\pic at (z) {tick};
\draw (c) to["2"{draw,circle},my curve] (b) to ["3"{draw,circle},my curve] (a) to ["1"{draw,circle},my curve](z);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I want region 1 represent (a, \infty), so the curve starting from $a$ should not point to any other number, how should I modify the code? One more thing, what if I want to add a caption underneath the figure?

Comment: @luw Is this right for you now?

Comment: It's great! Thank you for your detailed explanation!

Comment: Hi! Can I add a question? What if I want to represent the region (-\infty, c). I think I need to modify your "infty", but I don't know how.

Comment: @luw I just added a style for this

Comment: You are finally back...welcome with all my heart and happy holidays.

Comment: @Sebastiano Not really, I don't have time to get involved in the site right now, I'm just answering a request. Happy New Year 2021 to you!

Comment: @AndréC I will return my besttttt wishes for the new year and I hope for you and your family a good year that it will be better than this baddddd year. All the best...always.

Comment: @AndréC Thank you so much! Happy holidays!